# matplotlib.basemap - Earth Science - ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12529,15661) (12529,15662)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, netcdf4

Can't seem to figure out why my graph will not come out correctly. I am attempting to plot depth on a map projection using netCDF4, and mpl_toolkits.Basemap. I have attempted several projections yet none have worked. Below is the code I am using:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import mpl_toolkits as mplt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f = Dataset("/geosci/path2data/depth_data.nc")

# extract and label column
lats = f.variables['lat'][:]  # extract/copy the latitude data
lons = f.variables['lon'][:]  # extract/copy the longitude data
depth = f.variables['Band1'][:]
lon_0 = lons.mean()
lat_0 = lats.mean()


#create map projection
m = Basemap(projection = 'stere', width = 5*10**6, height = 35*10**5, resolution = 'l', lat_ts = 40, lat_0 = lat_0, lon_0 = lon_0)

# Plot of global temperature on our random day
fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0., right=1., bottom=0., top=0.9)

# Make the plot continuous
depth_cyclic, lons_cyclic = mplt.basemap.addcyclic(depth, lons) 

# compute map projection coordinates for lat/lon grid
# Create 2D lat/lon arrays for Basemap
lon2d, lat2d = np.meshgrid(lons_cyclic, lats)
# Transforms lat/lon into plotting coordinates for projection
x, y = m(lon2d, lat2d)

# Plot of air temperature with 11 contour intervals
cs = m.contourf(lon2d, lat2d, depth, 11, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral_r)
cbar = plt.colorbar(cs, orientation='horizontal', shrink=0.5)
m.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

This is the error I get in return. Still teaching myself to code and need a little bit of help on this one.

> ```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-7-7b81b2da3866> in <module>()
>      18 
>      19 # Plot of air temperature with 11 contour intervals
> ---> 20 cs = m.contourf(lon2d, lat2d, depth, 11, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral_r)
>      21 cbar = plt.colorbar(cs, orientation='horizontal', shrink=0.5)
>      22 m.plot(x,y)
>
> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.pyc
> in with_transform(self, x, y, data, *args, **kwargs)
>     519             # convert lat/lon coords to map projection coords.
>     520             x, y = self(x,y)
> --> 521         return plotfunc(self,x,y,data,*args,**kwargs)
>     522     return with_transform
>     523 
>
> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.pyc
> in contourf(self, x, y, data, *args, **kwargs)
>    3669                 data = ma.asarray(data)
>    3670                 # combine with data mask.
> -> 3671                 mask = np.logical_or(ma.getmaskarray(data),xymask)
>    3672                 data = ma.masked_array(data,mask=mask)
>    3673                 CS = ax.contourf(x,y,data,*args,**kwargs)
>
> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12529,15661) (12529,15662)
> ```

Comment: What this error tells you is that the data `depth` has one more column than x and/or y (`lon2d, lat2d`). Since this is no [mcve], I think this is all we can help you with.

Comment: Forgive me for asking: How can I make this a better question? I personally believe that I laid out the issue pretty clearly.

Comment: From the guides *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce **it in the question itself**."* So a good question would not use an input file at all but reproduce the problem with some data inside the question.

Comment: Yeah I got that part but if you notice in my code I created x, y data based on the depth information. I think this question is really for people who are Earth Scientists. Read the code again and you will see it. Do you have experience with Numpy arrays?

Comment: This question is about arrays not having the correct shape to be broadcast together. Whether doing earth or space sciences is rather irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to the continuous depth which was assigned to the other information.

cs = m.contourf(x, y, depth_cyclic, 11, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral_r)